# If statement overwriting .append in for loop

Tags: python

If statement overwrites .append function. I believe this due to the if statement being in the for loop but I am unsure. How i would fix this. The code was working before until i added the if statement to turn rider's placing into points. I have tried many different ways for the if statement/loop to work, But nothing has worked.

```
first_place = 5
second_place = 3
third_place = 1
other_placing = 0

runner1 = input("What is the name of the first runner in your team?")
runner2 = input("What is the name of the second runner in your team?")
runner3 = input("What is the name of the third runner in your team?")

runner_stats = []  # This will end up having 3 entries by the end of the loop.
for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    race1 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 1:"))
    race2 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 2:"))
    race3 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 3:"))
    race4 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 4:"))

if race1 >= 4:
 points_race_1  = (other_placing)
elif race1 == 3:
 points_race_1  = (third_place)
elif race1 == 2:
 points_race_1  = (second_place)
elif race1 == 1:
 points_race_1 = (first_place)

if race2 >= 4:
 points_race_2 = (other_placing)
elif race2 == 3:
 points_race_2 = (third_place)
elif race2 == 2:
 points_race_2 = (second_place)
elif race2 == 1:
 points_race_2 = (first_place)


if race3 >= 4:
 points_race_3 = (other_placing)
elif race3 == 3:
 points_race_3 = (third_place)
elif race3 == 2:
 points_race_3 = (second_place)
elif race3 == 1:
 points_race_3 = (first_place)


if race4 >= 4:
 points_race_4 = (other_placing)
elif race4 == 3:
 points_race_4 = (third_place)
elif race4 == 2:
 points_race_4 = (second_place)
elif race4 == 1:
 points_race_4 = (first_place)

runner_stats.append({
        "RacerName": name,
        "Race1Placing": race1,
        "Race1Points": points_race_1,
        "Race2Placing": race2,
        "Race2Points": points_race_2,
        "Race3Placing": race3,
        "Race3Points": points_race_3,
        "Race4Placing": race4,
        "Race4Points": points_race_4,
    })

print(runner_stats)
```

Working code before if statement.

```
runner1 = input("What is the name of the first runner in your team?")
runner2 = input("What is the name of the second runner in your team?")
runner3 = input("What is the name of the third runner in your team?")

runner_stats = []  # This will end up having 3 entries by the end of the loop.
for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    race1 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 1:"))
    race2 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 2:"))
    race3 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 3:"))
    race4 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 4:"))

    runner_stats.append({
        "RacerName": name,
        "Race1Placing": race1,
        "Race2Placing": race2,
        "Race3Placing": race3,
        "Race4Placing": race4,
    })

print(runner_stats)
```

Comment: I think just your intends are wrong. Put all the ifs in the for loop also the runn_stats.append()  like you did in your working code.

Comment: @Sharku Thankyou. Forgot to re-indent my code after my previous try's.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with the indentation of the for loop:

- the **if statement** as you wrote it **is not inside** the for loop, it is in fact outside the loop since it is indented at the same level.
- the append instruction is outside the loop, **only the last racer** will be added to the list, so your problem is probably here.

This is the correct loop code with the addition of a function to calculate the points, so you don't need to write the same code multiple times, remember to always define functions instead or rewriting the same code over and over again:

```
first_place = 5
second_place = 3
third_place = 1
other_placing = 0

runner1 = input("What is the name of the first runner in your team?")
runner2 = input("What is the name of the second runner in your team?")
runner3 = input("What is the name of the third runner in your team?")

runner_stats = []  # This will end up having 3 entries by the end of the loop.

def race_points(race):

    if race >= 4:
     points = (other_placing)
    elif race == 3:
     points = (third_place)
    elif race == 2:
     points = (second_place)
    elif race == 1:
     points = (first_place)

    return points

for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    race1 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 1:"))
    race2 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 2:"))
    race3 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 3:"))
    race4 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 4:"))

    points_race_1 = race_points(race1)
    points_race_2 = race_points(race2)
    points_race_3 = race_points(race3)
    points_race_4 = race_points(race4)    

    runner_stats.append({
            "RacerName": name,
            "Race1Placing": race1,
            "Race1Points": points_race_1,
            "Race2Placing": race2,
            "Race2Points": points_race_2,
            "Race3Placing": race3,
            "Race3Points": points_race_3,
            "Race4Placing": race4,
            "Race4Points": points_race_4,
        })

print(runner_stats)
```

You could also directly use the points function when you append, without the need to define the *points_race* variables:

```
runner_stats.append({
        "RacerName": name,
        "Race1Placing": race1,
        "Race1Points": race_points(race1),
        "Race2Placing": race2,
        "Race2Points": race_points(race2),
        "Race3Placing": race3,
        "Race3Points": race_points(race3),
        "Race4Placing": race4,
        "Race4Points": race_points(race4),
    })
```